# Why can't I create a move constructor with the old reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I'm learning how to create move constructors, so I made a class called Test that has one, just like the ones in the tutorials:

```
class Test {
private:
    int* arr;
    int size;

public:
    Test() {
        arr = new int[100];
        size = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
    }

    Test(Test&& other) {
        arr = other.arr;
        size = other.size;
        other.arr = nullptr;
        other.size = 0;
    }
};
```

Out of curiosity, I removed the Rvalue reference to see if it worked with the "old reference":

```
class Test {
private:
    int* arr;
    int size;

public:
    Test() {
        arr = new int[100];
        size = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
    }

    Test(Test& other) {
        arr = other.arr;
        size = other.size;
        other.arr = nullptr;
        other.size = 0;
    }
};
```

To my surprise, it worked perfectly. So my question is:
If we were able to build perfectly good move constructors before, why did they add this to the language?

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` would be a fun read, regarding _what we were able to do before_.

Comment: _"it worked perfectly"_ did you try passing a temporary to your version that doesn't use rvalue references?  [Lets see how well this code works](https://godbolt.org/z/n9KdTe).

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector` Use Constructor Lists.

Comment: Dont think of it as a "move" constructor only, also see it as an *rvalue reference* constructor. And the second variant can't handle all the cases the first can, or a proper copy constructor. In fact when used as a copy constructor the behavior will be quite suprising.

Comment: Hmm if it worked perfectly without copy constructor and destructor then we do not need move semantics...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You said the second variant can't handle all the cases the first can. What would be an example of one case that the second variant can't handle?

Comment: Short answer - because it will compile where it should not and fail where it should compile.

Comment: `Test(Test& other) ` is not a [*move* constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), it is a [*copy* constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) that is improperly implementing move semantics instead of copy semantics.

Comment: Where can I see an example of a code that shows how the second approach fails?

Comment: *"it worked perfectly"* - Either your test is flawed, or you used MSVC without setting `/permissive-` in which case it's still a flawed test TBH.

Comment: @MrPresident Taken from [the answer by Jeffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537227/440558): `Test a(someFunction()) ;`. The second version, with the non-constant reference, should fail to build with that.

Answer (score 3):

With what you are suggesting, the same thing happens in the first and third case below:

```
Test someFunction();

Test a;

Test b(a);              // 1. as a developer I wanted a copy 
Test c(someFunction()); // 2. I expect the compiler to move the return value
Test d(std::move(a));   // 3. here, I wanted a move, as I don't care about a anymore
```

So, of the three cases above, your suggestion doesn't distinguish the first and third. This is what r-value reference offer: figuring out the context and distinguishing between references that can be moved and those that cannot.